What type of potentiometer has no shaft but can be secured with a nut and washer?
[![enter code here][1]][1]Location where potentiometer needs to be attached:

Plate where potentiometer is attached:

I am looking for a potentiometer that has no shaft that can be screwed with a a nut and washer. Which one do your recommend?
I am using this potentiometer to measure motion which converts to swing weight for a tennis racquet.


Define how the wiper moves without a shaft.

Can you show us a photo with a view of the front?

it is unclear what you want ... what mechanism would change the potentiometer wiper position? ... please update your post with an explanation

Good question people! To give you an explanation how the wiper moves, there are three wires attached to the potentiometer. There is also a 4 pin atx connector that plugs into the motherboard. The software calculates the swightweight based on the number of times the racquet moves back and forth. Potentiometer is attached to a shaft.

The wiper moves by attaching the potentiometer as the bottom of the plate shown below. Since the original potentiometer has no shaft, it was screwed in with a built in shaft which came with the machine.

Please add new information and clarification to your question by [edit]ing it. While you're at it, please show how exactly the existing shaft connects to the potentiometer.

The potentiometer is labelled CONTELEC PD 280 - 1K0/J. I can't find any details on the https://www.contelec.ch/ site but a google image search contelec pd280 find similar looking items with a shaft.

So, has the shaft been removed from the CONTELEC PD 280 - 1K0/J before being fitted to the equipment?

To give you an explanation how the wiper moves, there are three wires attached to the potentiometer.  Wires do not move.  The potentiometer has no shaft, but is attached to something that turns.  So how are the two connected.  As in a really short shaft.  You can adjust a shaftless potentiometer with a screw driver.

@ChesterGillon correct the shaft has been removed prior to fitting the equipment. Weird they did for the manufacturer.

This appears to be a fully custom shaft variation on a standard Contelec part, made for this particular manufacturer. Also, being Swiss and high-precision, quite an expensive potentiometer (guesstimate USD 100 for a new standard unit in one-off).
The closest search term for something similar is probably "hollow shaft potentiometer, however that's not exactly what you have. It seems to be open at one end only and mate to the shaft through a knurl or spline that allows some misalignment and relative motion.
If there is room behind the mounting bracket you might be able to rig something up with a conventional precision (perhaps conductive plastic over wirewound) servo pot and a shaft coupler that will deal with small misalignment. It still won't be cheap to duplicate the original precision- I suggest buying a replacement from the machine manufacturer or a used unit from a scrapped system might be a more viable approach.
Typical (image from here ) 6mm:6.35mm multi-beam type shaft coupler (the cuts allow the shafts to be slightly misaligned so they don't bind, yet retain stiffness in the rotary direction):


Thanks for the info @Spehro! Your right a hallow potentiometer may work. To add context here is the shaft that came with the pot after removing the Allen screw.

@Jasen may be correct though, could be overthinking this. It would be easier if the parts were in front of us.

Loosen this screw using a hex key of the apropriate size

Then pull out the old broken off potentiometer shaft and install a new potentiometer, and tighten the screw back up.
To you answer your question "what kind..."
A broken one!
